# MySQL Query Problems for error ''

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi all i have been writing a query and it is driving me crazy because it is giving me syntax error for ''

my query is

```
UPDATE test1 SET result = 
CASE WHEN formula = "p1+p2" THEN 2
```

the error is here on line 2
any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing an `end` on the `case`.  It might still not do what you want, but that is another issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are genius man you saved my day, thanks a lot man. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` should always have an `end`:

```
UPDATE test1
    SET result = (CASE WHEN formula = 'p1+p2' THEN 2 END);
```

This sets `result` to either "2" or `NULL`.  You probably want:

```
UPDATE test1
    SET result = 2
    WHERE formula = 'p1+p2';
```

As a general rule, use single quotes for string constants.  This is the ANSI standard.

Comment: SET result=2. You are missing 2

Comment: Ok i have another question can we write more than one WHERE Clause in  single sql query? like SET col1 = value1 WHERE col3  = value3, col2=value2 WHERE col4=value4 ?

Comment: @Tahir Apart from subqueries, which each may have their own `WHERE`, there is only room for maximum a single `WHERE` per statement.

Comment: @Tahir . . . No.  You use `AND` or `OR` to connect boolean expressions, not `WHERE`.